# "sample larger than population" in random.sample python

Tags: python, string, random

creating a simple pass generator for myself, i noticed that if i want my population to be digits only (0-9) which is overall 10 options, if i want my length over 10, it wont use any of the digits more then once and return the "sample larger then population" error.

is it possible to maintain the code, but add/reduce code lines so it works? or do i HAVE To use a use random choice?

```
import string
import random

z=int(raw_input("for: \n numbers only choose 1, \n letters only choose 2, \n letters and numbers choose 3, \n for everything choose 4:"))

if z==1:
    x=string.digits
elif z==2:
    x=string.letters
elif z==3:
    x=string.letters+string.digits
elif z==4:
    x=string.letters+string.digits+string.punctuation
else:
    print "die in a fire"

y=int(raw_input("How many passwords would you like?:"))
v=int(raw_input("How long would you like the password to be?:"))

for i in range(y):
    string=""
    for n in random.sample(x,v):
        string+=n
    print string
```

ty

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The *purpose* of `random.sample()` is to pick a *subset* of the input sequence, randomly, without picking any one element more than once. If your input sequence has no repetitions, neither will your output.

You are *not* looking for a subset; you want single random choices from the input sequence, repeated a number of times. Elements can be used more than once. Use `random.choice()` in a loop for this:

```
for i in range(y):
    string = ''.join([random.choice(x) for _ in range(v)])
    print string
```

This creates a string of length `v`, where characters from `x` can be used more than once.

Quick demo:

```
>>> import string
>>> import random
>>> x = string.letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
>>> v = 20
>>> ''.join([random.choice(x) for _ in range(v)])
'Ms>V\\0Mf|W@R,#/.P~Rv'
>>> ''.join([random.choice(x) for _ in range(v)])
'TsPnvN&qlm#mBj-!~}3W'
>>> ''.join([random.choice(x) for _ in range(v)])
'{:dfE;VhR:=_~O*,QG<f'
```

Comment: you are a GENIUS! you solved it so quickly that i can't even choose the answer yet, will do so in 5 mins. quick quetion tho (you don't have to answer i know its a diff question, i just want to understand) - does this render sample useless? because it does exactly the same but more...

Comment: No, `sample()` has a *different* purpose. Imagine picking 4 random cards from a deck of cards. You cannot pick the same card twice, you need to pick 4 unique cards from the deck. That is a sample.

Comment: Your solution is right, but I think it's incorrect to say that a sample by definition is a subset.  The difference is between sampling with and without replacement (see, e.g., [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_%28statistics%29)).  Also, the `numpy.random.choice` function has an option to choose whether to sample with or without replacement, so that can be useful if you're dealing with numpy structures.

Comment: @BrenBarn: The `random.sample()` implementation is very much sampling *without* replacement, as `random.choice()` with a loop makes it easy to implement the other option.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Sure, and your edit has made things clear.  I'm just saying there's a difference between what `random.sample` does and "what a sample by definition is".

Comment: A sample is not always a subset. There's a very useful statistical technique called [bootstrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)) which re-samples a small set of data to improve estimates.

Comment: Yup, I very much stand corrected; that's why I edited the answer. :-)

Answer (score 8):

Since the python_3.6 you can use `random.choices(x, k=v)` for your purpose. It returns a k sized list of elements chosen from the population with replacement. If the population is empty, raises IndexError.

Answer (score 3):

@Martijn Pieters is right.
But since they state at https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/random.html:

> *Warning: The pseudo-random generators of this module should not be used for security purposes. Use os.urandom() or SystemRandom if you require a cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator.*

and the purpose of this is for generating passwords, I suggest this approach:

```
import string
import random

set = string.letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
length = 20

password = ''.join( [ random.SystemRandom().choice( set) for _ in range( length) ] )

print( password)
```

Could anybody please confirm that this is more secure?

Comment: or just `random.choice(chars)` I'm running my version of this program right now just out of curiosity