# Generate a random string with a random number of letters and spaces

Tags: python

I have written a function that returns a random string of length `n`.

```
import string, random
def randomString(N):
    return ''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase + ' ', N))
```

However, this only ever returns a string with one of each letter/space. I need a string with a random number of lowercase letters and spaces (characters can repeat).

I have tried adding another argument to the .join method and it returns a syntax error.

How can I change this function to produce a random number of letters and spaces?

Comment: So... what is your question?

Comment: No, **no**, you should most definitely *not* update your question as you go along after getting fed the answers.  SO is not designed to do your homework for you.

Comment: We'd prefer if you didn't update your question.  Ask a new question if you have one. Also, while the pre-amble is lovely, it is mostly irrelevant.  Your question should be along the lines of: `"How can I generate a random string composed of 27 ascii lowercase letters plus the space?"`  That is all you're really asking.

Comment: random.sample returns unique samples.

Comment: This is the question you should have asked. Everything else is either irrelevant or part of one or more future questions.

Comment: Oops, thanks for updating the title. I forgot to also edit that.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist You completely changed the meaning of the question. Before, it wanted a string of 27 letters/spaces. Now it's asking for a string composed of the letters a-z (once each) plus a number of spaces.

Comment: @interjay Where are you getting the once each thing? And how did I completely change the meaning of the question by simply removing a large irrelevant description of the backstory?

Comment: @antwontheswan2 Do you think a monkey will favor space to other characters?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist The current code uses `random.sample`, which would return each letter once. And the only requested change in the edited question is to return more than one space. The backstory which you removed makes it clear that each letter should be able to appear any number of times.

Comment: Take a look at the selected answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861497/sample-larger-than-population-in-random-sample-python

Comment: @interjay Edited to clarify. Still did not add back the backstory. I really hesitate to say that whole explanation is necessary context here...

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I agree. Some context is fine but that was way too much. It's much clearer now.

Answer (score 3):

```
from random import choice
from string import ascii_lowercase

# vary the number of spaces appended to adjust the probability
chars = ascii_lowercase + " " * 10

def random_string(n):
    return "".join(choice(chars) for _ in range(n))
```

then

```
>>> print(random_string(15))
fhr qhay nuf u
```

---

As with the number of spaces, you can adjust the number of times each char appears to change its relative probability:

```
chars = (
    '                                                !,,,,,--....'
    '.....:;aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbcccccccccdddddddddeeeeeeeee'
    'eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeefffffggggghhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiijj'
    'klllllllllmmmmmmnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnooooooooooooooooppppppwrrr'
    'rrrrrrrrrrrrrssssssssssssssssttttttttttttttttttttuuuuuuuvvvw'
    'wwxyyyyz'
)

for _ in range(5):
    print(random_string(30))
```

gives

```
sxh ehredi clo-ioodmttlpoir.wo
ijr thc -o,iepe.pcicfrn.osui.a
 et rtl teektet rrecyd.d .bate
aji ueava hahe arv tgnrnt eecs
a ne:tudsdu,nlnhbeirp,oioitt e
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice)

```
import string, random
def randomString(N):
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + ' ') for i in range(N))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can very easily do this with a simple loop, using `random.choice` rather than `random.sample` to do it all at once:

```
>>> import string, random
>>> def random_string(n):
...   count = 0
...   s = ''
...   while count < n:
...     s += random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + ' ')
...     count += 1
...   return s
... 
>>> random_string(27)
'amwq frutj nq dbotgllrbmhnj'
>>> random_string(27)
'khjnmhvgzycqm vyjqcttybuqm '
>>> random_string(27)
'ssakcpeesfe kton gigblmgo o'
```